# Android Drop up(?) menu possible?

Tags: android, listview, drop-down-menu

Ok so I'm trying to figured out how i can make a menu similar to a drop down menu, but it goes up instead of down. I'm wanting something similar to [This](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/94/screenshot20091217at142.png/). It would mean I would be creating a list-view. But I'm not sure how it would all work, since I'm using Image-buttons I made in Photoshop. It has to possible since adobe has pretty much done it. But my questions is how? Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is a standard `ToggleButton` with a background selector that is transparent when not activated and with a transparent black one when active. When the `ToggleButton` gets pressed, a [PopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html) will be displayed below. The content of this window should be a standard ViewGroup/layout that was passed to that window (transparent black background with a few clickable `TextView`s basically)